# Error near 'BIT' when attempting to create MySql Table

Tags: mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BIT)' at line 1

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Clients (ID nvarchar(36), Primary BIT)
```

I have also tried bit(1) and tinyint(1). any Ideas?

Comment: "Primary" is a reserved word. Try another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the word 'Primary' is reserved for indicating whether a column is a primary key.  You need to pick a different column name.

Answer (score -1):

Missing semi colon at the end.